# vim settings for python

Tags: python, vim

I have the following settings file:

```
# ~/.vimrc
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set smarttab
set expandtab
set softtabstop=4
set autoindent
```

How would I make these settings apply to **python only**? Also, how would I add python coloring (such as textmate does for each language) ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have these lines in my config:

```
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py set tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 expandtab smarttab autoindent
```

This may be what you're looking for with the coloring:
[Improved Python syntax, Blackboard color scheme](http://concisionandconcinnity.blogspot.com/2009/07/vim-part-i-improved-python-syntax.html)

Comment: I don't think you need all the separators `|`, you can do it all in one `set` with `set tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 shifwitdth=4 expandtab...`

Comment: @skeept Thanks! I updated my answer (and my vim config) to remove the extra set's.

Answer (score 6):

Put them in `vimfiles/ftplugin/python.vim` (but change `set` to `setlocal`) and add `filetype plugin on` to `.vimrc`. For syntax highlighting, add `syntax on` to `.vimrc`.

Comment: It this `~/.vim/vimfiles/ftplugin/python.vim` or where is the exact location of the file?

Comment: You have to put it into `~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, try your hand at [vim-janus](https://github.com/alanleftofthedot/Vim-Janus) which adds other goodies to vim.