# Use Vim Retab to solve TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation?

Tags: python, vim

Apologize for the newbie question, but I have read the manual, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024435/how-to-fix-python-indentation) question, and tried several times without results I expected.

So I was using vim to edit a file (attached). But when running, I got the TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation error.

Here is what I have tried:

- Open the file with Vim. type `:retab`, and `:x`. Run the file again. Still got the TabError message.
- Open the file again and type `:retab!` and `:x`. Run the file again. Still got the TabError message.
- Open the file again and type `:retab! 4` and `:x`. Run the file again. This time it works but I have no idea why? Plus, in the files indentation seems excessively long. (I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685406/inconsistent-use-of-tabs-and-spaces-in-indentation) that the editor might display 8 spaces for a tab)

**My questions are:**

- What does `:retab`, `:retab!`, and `:retab! 4` mean?
- Why doesn't `:retab` work on my file?

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env python
  #Reduce function for computing matrix multiply A*B    
  #Input arguments:
  #variable n should be set to the inner dimension of the matrix product (i.e., the number of columns of A/rows of B) 
  import sys
  import string
  import numpy

  #number of columns of A/rows of B
  n = int(sys.argv[1]) 

  #Create data structures to hold the current row/column values (if needed; your code goes here)

  currentkey = None
  alist = [] # list for elelents in  A
  blist = [] # list for elements in B
  # input comes from STDIN (stream data that goes to the program)
  for line in sys.stdin:
      #Remove leading and trailing whitespace
      line = line.strip()
      #Get key/value 
      key, value = line.split('\t',1)
      print(key, value)
      #Parse key/value input (your code goes here)
      key = (key.split(',', 1)[0], key.split(',',1)[1])   
      value = (value.split(',', 1)[0], value.split(',',1)[1], value.split(',',1)[2])  
      #If we are still on the same key...
      if key==currentkey:
          #Process key/value pair (your code goes here)
          # store all values in a lisl
          if value[0]=='A':
          alist.append([value[1], value[2]])
          else:
          blist.append([value[1], value[2]])
          #Otherwise, if this is a new key...
      else:
      #If this is a new key and not the first key we've seen, i.e. currentkey!=None
          if currentkey:
      #compute/output result to STDOUT (your code goes here)
          alist = sorted(alist)
          blist = sorted(blist)
          newlist = [a[1]*b[1] for a,b in zip(alist, blist)]
          res = newlist.sum() 
          print(currentkey, res)
          currentkey = key
          #Process input for new key (your code goes here)
  ```

Comment: You say you have read the manual, did you type `:help retab` in Vim?

Comment: @promatico Thanks for the reply! The manual is a bit technical and I'm not sure I understand it correctly. I guess `:retab! 4` means a tab is changed to 4 spaces? If this is the case, why doesn't `:retab` or `:retab!`work?

Comment: They do work. try `%:retab! 4` or `%:retab 4`, but after `:set list` to see the tabs as tabs. Sometimes they do nothing because there is nothing to be done.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just type `:help retab` in Vim and read. I think I can't explain it better than the help. Maybe you are missing the optional range part; use `%` prefix to apply to the whole file. Also useful is `:set list` to show you every chars; this will show you the tabs and line ends (disable with `:set nolist`) and `:set <name>` with no value to see the current value, ex `: set tabstop` or followed by some value to set.

By showing all chars, enabling and disabling expansion of tabs into spaces with `:set expandtab` and `:set noexpandtab`, setting tabstop and by using for ex. `:retab! 4` you can play your way around and switch from tabs only and spaces only, and change the tab column width.

This link, [vim settings for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760082/vim-settings-for-python) might be useful also

Comment: Just some tangential vim advice: Whenever I'm manually toggling an option with exactly two states, on or off, rather than using the explicit `:set <option>`/`:set no<option>`, I like to use `:set <option>!`. The exclamation mark toggles the state of the option, whether it's currently on *or* off.
That way, if I want to toggle it again in a few minutes, I can just hit `:` and the up arrow once or a few times, to re-run exactly the same command. Simpler than worrying about whether the "`no`" is there or not.
Of course, in your vimrc, you'll still want the explicit setting.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! With :set list I was able to see exactly how many tabs in my scripts and undersood why the script looked ugly. It's also good to know the use of %. @Edward I unfortunately don't exactly understand your advice at the moment, but I'm sure they might be useful sometime in the future!

Comment: @yuqli, to clarify: If `list`, for example, is turned off and you want to turn it on, you have two choices - `:set list` OR `:set list!`. Then to turn `list` off again later, you can use `:set nolist`, OR you can use `:set list!` again. The "!" here means "whatever the current state of the option", flip it to the opposite.
Now the business with the up arrow: If you have typed a command with ":" lately, that you want to use again, you can save retyping it by hitting ":" and then the up arrow (repeatedly), to scroll through your past commands in reverse-chronological order. Then Enter to select

Comment: @Edward I understand it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Esc

```
:%s/\t/    /g
```

It means to replace the tab with 4 spaces. Hit Enter
Esc

```
:wq
```

Comment: The '4 spaces'? Is this the space between the two `/` in your command?

Comment: Yes, it is space

Answer (score 2):

While just trying to run `:retab` might not work if you have copy pasted code and started to edit it.

You can try setting the vim/vi settings first:

1. Check if you have ~/.vim/vimrc file else run `sudo mkdir ~/.vim && sudo touch ~/.vim/vimrc` to create settings file
2. once created edit `vimrc` to add below snippet

```
    set softtabstop=4
    set tabstop=4
    set shiftwidth=4
    set expandtab
```

3. open your file using vim/vi and run `:retab`