# Indentation issue with python3 and vim

Tags: python, vim, ubuntu-16.04

A sample of my python file is

```
def __init__(self, csvFile, chunksize=10000):
        self.newName = csvFile[:-4]
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
        self.csvFile=csvFile
        self.chunksize=int(chunksize)
        self.headers_without_timestamp = header_without_timestamp 

        self.total_rows = 0
        self.username=username
        self.password=password
        self.dbname="data"
```

and it is well written.

I have the little error, but I can't fix it. When I ran the command `python3 Final_Fast_Version_Waqar.py ~/home/Data/DCIX_OB.csv 1000 7`, I got

```
  File "Final_Fast_Version_Waqar.py", line 37
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
                                ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

It is a problem related to the vim editor I guess because I set up an Ubuntu server and installed vim very recently. How can I fix the indentation error?

Comment: Indentation should be four spaces, i think you are using 8 spaces in your tab

Comment: `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()`, the `;` is suspicious, it is perl syntax

Comment: @Gang It's not, it's valid Python syntax.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48735671/use-vim-retab-to-solve-taberror-inconsistent-use-of-tabs-and-spaces-in-indentat

Comment: The semi-colon is valid, but not appropriate outside of short snippets intended for `exec` or command-line one-liners. (I.e, don't use it in a script.)

Comment: @chepner that single line is what is provided in the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) as the example of how to use `pdb`. I assume this recommendation is in here to allow for easy, obvious cleanup and "turning on/off" the debugger with comments when using `pdb` or `ipdb`.

Answer (score 8):

Since Python is sensitive to indentation, it is desirable to configure your editor to use spaces instead of tabs. For vim, you can add this to your `.vimrc`

```
set tabstop=4
```

Every  time you type *tab*, vim will use 4 spaces instead.

Also, to fix the indentation of your current file, type:

```
:retab
```

Comment: Already written in my `.vimrc` file

Answer (score 6):

It might be helpful to turn on white-space characters in vim to see what is happening.

```
:set listchars=eol:¬,tab:>·,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<,space:·
```

What you'll probably see is a mix where some lines use tabs (`>·`) and others use spaces (`··`), something that's not allowed in python.

I'd recommend setting up your vim config so that it automatically switches tabs to spaces in python. Maybe something like?

```
autocmd Filetype python setlocal ts=4 sw=4 sts=0 expandtab
```